# why airplane mode turns on automatically?

Tags: networking, wireless, airplane-mode

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 on a fujitsu T901 laptop. Ubuntu automatically activates airplane mode and therefore wifi turns off and connection gets lost. there is no obvious pattern that I could understand but every now and then it happens. I have checked my hardware driver installation and turned off power saving ... nothing has worked yet. anybody has an idea how could I fix that? if more information is needed I will provide. thanks for your attention.

Comment: happens to me on 20.10 everytime I put my laptop to sleep.

Comment: Yes, it randomly turns on and off.  Works fine for long periods of time and then spends an hour popping into and out of airplane mode randomly.  Super frustrating.  X1 Carbon 2021  Ubuntu 21.10